A full Telugu reading of the Mahabharatam?
The Mahabharatam is quite central to the subcontinent's history and I feel the need to know it. I wish to do a full reading of it in my native language, and it was suggested to me that Puripanda Appalaswamy's translation is quite good (I am not sure whether it is a full translation or if it's abridged). It has 6 volumes and all 18 parvams.
I want to be methodical about it and not just read it for the sake of having read it. I want to maintain notes and annotations to wrap my head around it as I hear it is immensely complex. Do you have any suggestions about the Telugu translation, and about the right approach to take in general? Thanks.

https://devullu.com/books/mahabharatham/        Cost Rs 555/-
